# Minimum least common multiplier for variable combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I looking to find the minimum possible value of the LCM of a variable set of integers.

My hypotheses are the following:

- I have a set $N$ of $n$ integers, all different.
- My integers are bounded by $min$ and $max$
- I know the exact value of some integers in $N$. Lets call $A = \{a1,...,am\}$ the subset of the known values.

I'm trying to find the smallest possible LCM of all the integers in $N$.

For example, for $n = 4, min=1, max=10, A= \{2\}$
 we have the resulting set:

$N = \{2,x,y,z\} $

$1<x,y,z<10$ and $x \neq y$, $x \neq z$,$y \neq z$ , and $x,y,z \neq 2$

For this specific case the minimum LCM of N is
$minLCM(N) = 6$ for $N = \{2,1,3,6\}$

I'm not interested in the values of x,y,z, nor the number of combinations that produce my result, only in the minimum possible LCM

I can find a result for specific cases by brute force programming but I'd love a more general and elegant way of doing it, if there is one.

Thanks

Comment: The title says "random", but randomness doesn't actually seem to play a role in the question?

Comment: You're right, I'll edit. I use it in a program that choses random values, but the smallest lcm should not be random, my bad